# Two electric baseboard thermostats on one circuit. The first box has six wires, the second just four (ignoring the grounds)

Tags: electrical, thermostat, baseboard

At the first thermostat is the group of two wires the line, and the group of three wires the load? The second thermostat along the circuit only has four wires. I put in a new thermostat on the second one with four wires and it works. Don’t know how to wire the other thermostat because of the six wires(one group of two and one group of three). Basically which group is the line and which is the load?

Comment: Clear, focused pictures of the labeling of the terminals on the thermostats themselves (include brand/model of the 'stats), will help immensely. You can [edit] the info into your question. Without that, it may be quite difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Do you have a volt-ohm meter or  other electrical tester?

Comment: Typically, it's most likely the first box has power in, power out and the switched load connection to the heater, second box has power in and switched power to the load. Take pictures. But I'm unclear on what you are trying to accomplish.  Is this a new install? Are you replacing existing t-stats?   Please **EDIT** your question to make it more clear so we can give better answers.

Answer (score 2):

## What you have

[image]

- Black = phase L1 supply in and out
- Red = phase L2 supply in and out
- Brown = phase L1 to heater itself
- Orange = phase L2 to heater itself
- white box is thermostat.

*Of course, your colors are probably quite different.  If it helps, feel free to get a 5-pack of colored electrical tape and re-mark.*

## What you want

[image]

### What you *really* want

Heat pumps (mini-split or otherwise) which run 200-600% efficient and also provide air conditioning in summer. You're gonna go broke paying the electricity bill on those resistance heaters.

Comment: +1 Beautiful diagrams, very clear.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat incomplete because details weren't provided, but 6 wires is likely 3 cables, and you  are probably using two-pole stats.

One cable is hot from breaker.  Wires are opposing 120v hots, probably black and white, the white should be remarked as hot. Both wires need to connect via individual 3 wire pigtails that connect to the hot side of first stat, and to second cable that goes to second stat.

Third cable connects to the load side of first stat. This cable feeds the first baseboard.

Comment: How you determine which cable is which depends on what testing tools you have. There are trial/error methods if you have no testers.